# Как избавится от задержки слушателя в ViewPager и изменить угол восприятия горизонтальной прокрутки?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Если присмотреться, элементы viewPager-а идут не сразу за пальцем,а после прохождения последним некоторого расстояния. Откуда это? В каком-то методе супер ViewPager-a описано?
Это может быть защита от случайного скроллинга,я сначала думал что это связано с fakeDrag,но не.
Еще - как увеличить угол,при котором свайп влияет на viewPager?Тоесть по деволту воспринимается все что в диапазоне градусов ~45-~225 если справа-налево и ~135-~315 для слева-направо,а как заставить работать при любом наличии смещения в горизонтальной плоскости,даже если значение смещения точки нажатия по вертикали больше чем по горизонтали?

Comment: Я помню лазил в исходниках ScrollView и наткнулся в onTouchEvent на  эту самую константу, откройте код ViewPager-a и найдете тоже

Comment: Именно! Порылся в viewPager-овском тач ивенте и если я правильно понял,в нем есть переменная  touchslop,которая помогает отделить свайп от длинного нажатия. С углами завтра разберусь уже